# How to display an action list on hover using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html page like  [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y2ee6fsc/) and when I hover the volume button which located on the right, the div box which contains the Upload and Delete function should be displayed beside with the volume icon. What I expect is when I hover the volume icon, the Upload, Delete and volume icon should be displayed in the same line, like picture below [image]
and grey panel will not be overflowed out of the box.

Does anyone have an idea how to set again the stylesheet to show this situation ?

Comment: Question title doesn't help... try "How to display an action list on hover using bootstrap?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make `.prompt-audio-control` display `inline-block` when they view on `hover` and not `inline` in order to fit next to each other:

```
.prompt-audio:hover .prompt-audio-control {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y2ee6fsc/2/

Comment: thanks KAD, it works but now I see that the Upload is a little bit higher than Delete, how can I fix it ?

Comment: The containers holding the upload and delete are different, delete in inside a `button` tag while upload is in a `div` tag, just make sure to use either of them, I will update the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Your elements that appear after `hover` had different value for `display` property. You can make them `inline-block`.

In order to make them on one line without changing html structure, you could remove `overflow: hidden` from `.btn-file`.

https://jsfiddle.net/wca36rqu/3/

Comment: thanks Anton, but the Upload and Delete are not really on the same line, the upload is a little bit higher than Delete, how can I fix it ?

Comment: @Son, I've fixed that too. Let me know if that works for you and consider accepting the answer (checkmark on the left of the question).

Answer (score 0):

i did some changes on your html and css maybe it will be help for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/j8p44she/

```
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 -2px 0;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: block;
}
.PlayPromptIcon, PlayPromptIcon:visited {
    color: grey;
}
.PlayPromptIcon:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}
.prompt-audio-control {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.prompt-audio:hover .prompt-audio-control, .prompt-audio:hover .nm li:nth-child(1), .prompt-audio:hover .nm li:nth-child(2) {
    display:inline-block;
}
.nm{
    margin:0px;
}
.nm li:nth-child(1), .nm li:nth-child(2){
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="input-group prompt" col-xs-2> <span class="input-group-addon">Prompt</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control tts-prompt" placeholder="Text to Speech Prompt!!" />
            <span class="input-group-addon prompt-audio">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline nm">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="prompt-audio-control" >
                        <div class="btn-file">
                            <input type="file" accept="audio/wav|audio/pcm|audio|vox" />
                            <span> Upload </span> 
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="btn-link prompt-audio-control" type="file"> <span> Delete </span> </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a class="PlayPromptIcon" target="_blank"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></a> </li>
            </ul>
            </span> </div>
    </div>
```